# Why wouldn’t the COM change position due to internal forces acting on objects inside a trolley?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, momentum

> 7.3 A child sits stationary at one end of a long trolley moving uniformly with a speed $V$ on a smooth horizontal floor.  If the child gets up a runs about on the trolley in any manner, what is the speed of the CM of the (trolley + child) system?

This is where I have got a bit of a problem. I do know that the COM would remain unaffected by internal forces in its system but according to my textbook those internal forces are supposed to cancel out each other. In the problem the internal forces seem to come from the child inside the trolley but I don’t see how those forces could cancel out and not affect the position of the COM. I have tried to think about this in an another way - if COM’s position is mathematically defined to be dependent on the mass and relative position of the objects in the system why wouldn’t it change when the child (an object of the system) changes their position by running around the trolley?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Newton's Third Law.

If the child exerts a force on the trolley, then the trolley must exert an equal and opposite force back on the child.  This means that the accelerations of the trolley and child respectively must satisfy
$$
m_t a_t = - m_c a_c.
$$
If we integrate both sides of the equation over some period of time we get
$$
m_t (v_t - V) = -m_c (v_c - V)
$$
where $V$ is the initial velocity.  Rearranging we see that
$$
\frac{m_t v_t + m_c v_c}{m_t + m_c} = V
$$
i.e., the center of mass is still moving at $V$ regardless of the forces the child and the trolley exert on each other.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Took some time to process everything. Thanks a lot mate!